# Border Color for UIButton in xcode 8 storyboard didn't work

Tags: uibutton, storyboard, border, swift3, xcode8

I have tried to implement answers from several stackoverflow questions for border color for a button. I implemented `layer.borderColor`  and also `layer.borderColorFromUIColor` in storyboard's user defined runtime attributes. But nothing seems to work. 
I am doing my project in Xcode 8 and swift 3. Please help.

Comment: try creating an IBOutlet to your view controller file. did you try it in that way

Comment: added the working answer, hope that will work for you. good luck

Answer (score 2):

do it like this. this works in run time.

[image]

hope this will help to you. good luck and have a nice day.

Comment: everything works fine but not able to change the color. i m getting only black border even though i m setting different color.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of what color you're applying is not set to the border. As per my understanding we can't set border color from storyboard as this property won't get reflected in the UIComponent at runtime. By default it is black color. If you want give a trial by removing the color property from Attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the border, You have to set both border color and border width.